# How to solve ' No route matches [GET] image.png ' when I moved image to assets image path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline, assets

I moved image to assets/images path from public/images

I have image:

```
 <%= image_tag("login_logo.png", :id => "login_logo") %>
```

I moved it from public folder to assets and changed path.

It is visible and working ok, but I get error in my console:

```
Started GET "/assets/logo_PG.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-10 23:42:53 +0300
 Served asset /logo_PG.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/login_logo.png")
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything in subdirectories of assets (regardless whether it is an image, JS, etc.) is by default available under `/assets/name.extension`. So just make sure you refer to the image with the path `/assets/login_logo.png`, or use the `asset_path` helper:

```
<%= asset_path('login_logo.png') %>
```

Comment: Image is showing - it is assets path, but error is showing. I will show you more code, maybe you will understand me better.

Comment: Please, look at my question again.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any hardcoded reference to "/images/login_logo.png" anywhere (CSS or JS maybe?). If you are using `asset_path` or `image_tag` in views/layouts, and `image-url`/`image-path` in the CSS files, Rails should provide the correct path always.

Comment: I found my problem. I had some file, which contained OLD PATH image. Excuse me, that disturbed you.